# Sticky footer hack is close, any tips to get me closer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky-footer

Here's the website: http://www.square1cards.com/

I'm trying to retrofit a responsive design with a sticky footer and so a lot of the CSS options we're incompatible and the fixed option really didn't satisfy either.

Since my top content (for the homepage) is a fixed height, through javascript I tried simply changing the top margin to the difference between the window height and that fixed value (when window height is greater than the fixed value).  A crude hack.

If you slowly resize the browser height it works fine but when you QUICKLY resize the height it causes the footer to jump off the screen slightly.  If I can resolve that, I should be ok.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's probably a result of processor and graphics card speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Matthew James Taylor's tutorial to be very useful.  It worked for me using only HTML and CSS.  I would highly recommend that approach instead of using JavaScript.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: I've decided to go with a bit of a hybrid solution relying on the absolute positioning and smoothness that comes with it but using JS to handle the - much easier to mitigate - width issues introduced with most CSS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I'm covering all known sticky footer techniques, or the techniques for what people (sometimes erroneously) call sticky footer, in [this tutorial](http://conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/how-to-get-100-height-css.php). Let us know if it helps you.